# Jenkins: Scan repositories after start-up?

Tags: jenkins

Suppose you push changes to a branch while Jenkins is down. When it starts back up I expect it to scan all repositories for changes and queue the builds it missed. But I'm not sure if there is an option to configure this.

We are using mostly multi-branch pipeline jobs, with Git.

Comment: Yes, as sson as it's up, it should scan for all changes since last build.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be doing this, which is why I asked... hmm... thank you though.

Comment: Add some more details; what is your SCM, how is the push notification configured? Are there any indicators in the logs of activity or error?

Comment: Updated -- we're using mostly multi-branch pipeline jobs, with Git.